# How to get retaining blocks with a set end angle

Tags: landscaping, concrete-block

I am trying to section off hexagonal areas in my yard. My initial thought was to get those trapezoidal blocks you can use to build retaining walls (Home Depot refers to them as [Retaining Wall Blocks](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Garden-Center-Hardscapes-Wall-Blocks-Retaining-Wall-Blocks/N-5yc1vZciam)), and use them to make the angles to get the (mostly) perfect hexagons.

However, having checked several local gardening center/box stores, I can only find blocks with 110 degree internal angles, which make nonogons (or decagons, might have messed up the calculation/drawing). I calculated it, and it appears I need 120 degree internal angles to make hexagons.

Here are a couple of rough diagrams of my calculations, to give you a sense of what I'm wanting.

**Hexagon**:

[image: A trapezoid with an internal angle of 120 degrees. The trapezoid is then copied and rotated 6 times until it forms a polygon with 6 sides.]

**Nonogon (not what I want):**
[image: A trapezoid with an internal angle of 110 degrees. The trapezoid is then copied and rotated 9 times until it forms a polygon with 9 sides.]

I also looked into pavers and edging stones, but those aren't usually trapezoidal, and if they are, also aren't the right angle.

How I can make hexagonal areas like this? These are intended to be permanent, and buried into the ground, so whatever is suggested needs to be able to stand up to that.

Comment: Hi @Tesset - could you not use a brick-saw / angle grinder / bolster to shape as needed?  Or take a squarer element and fill the gaps with mortar?  OR use the nonagon elements and leave a gap at the back - it's only the top row or capping that needs to look correct ...

Comment: I could rework what exists, though I do not generally have the tools/skills for those things. But I do actually need it to *be* correct, not just look correct, because I'm planning to tile the hexagons across an area, and that will fall apart quickly if I start fudging things (as I learned from attempt #1 with flags)

Comment: But I am not ruling out answers of "take an angle grinder to the thing" if there's also an explanation of how to make sure it's got the correct angles when I do it

Comment: An angle grinder probably not best tool, since it is usually done by sight.  Would suggest probably a wet saw that you rent, that has a fence you set to correct angle.